# Puzzled at this alternating series problem.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have rechecked this problem so many times, and even my tutor got stuck on this. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

[image]

My homework says I got at least one question wrong. And my tutor was confused too!.

Comment: The limit of $a_n$ doesn't exist; for large $n$, it more or less alternates $-1, 1$

Comment: how do u know that @SimonS for the limit i l hopitals rule and got 1

Comment: Look again at the definition of $a_n$!

Comment: Notice that your 3rd and 4th answers are incorrect.

Comment: @Elsa : The limit of the absolute value is $1$, but as you yourself said, it's alternating, so that'w where Simon got his conclusion.  If the limit is not $0$ then the series diverges. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user84413 oh ya srry i meant no for the 4th answer

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{n^2+8}{n^2+7}=1+\frac1{n^2+7}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and thus, as Simon commented, the general term's sequence does *not* converge to zero, and then the series diverges....and thus you have at least one answer wrong.